# Enable cursorline and cursorcolumn after Quickfix window is opened

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, quickfix, cursorline

Due to performance, I disable the `cursorline` and `cursorcolumn` in Vim. However, in the case jumping through a `Quickfix` window, it is hard to locate the cursor in the file. So I would like to enable `cursorline` and `cursorcolumn` automatically after a `Quickfix` window is opened (by whatever actions).

Now I have the solution using the `Autocmd` like this:

```
autocmd BufferEnter quickfix :bufdo set cursorline cursorcolumn
```

Is this the proper solution? Any better idea?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Maybe you could use the event QuickFixCmdPost ([`:h QuickFixCmdPost`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#QuickFixCmdPost)) instead but I'm not sure that would be better.

Comment: @statox Thanks, it works with `Ack`, `vimgrep` and so on. But it doesn't work in the case of `:copen`. Quite nice solution!

Comment: See [`:h QuickFixCmdPre`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#QuickFixCmdPre) it contains a list of the commands triggering the event `QuickFixCmdPre` (and thus the event `QuickFixCmdPost`) and indeed `:copen` is not one of them. So the behavior you're experiencing is normal but I don't know how to make it work with `:copen`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the file in `~/.vim/ftplugin/qf.vim` (or `$HOME/vimfiles/ftplugin/qf.vim` if you are on Windows) with the following contents:

```
" Only do this when not done yet for this buffer
if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
   finish
endif

wincmd p " go to original window
set cursorline
set cursorcolumn
wincmd p " back to quickfix window
```

The ftplugin files are executed whenever the filetype is set for a given file buffer (quickfix and location window has the filetyp `qf`).

Using the filetype plugin files instead of autocmds avoids cluttering your vimrc.
You can find more details at [`:help ftplugin-name`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_05.txt.html#ftplugin-name), [`:help 43`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_43.txt.html) and [Vim FAQ 26.8](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.8).

---

**Edit:**

The check on `b:did_ftplugin` is necessary to allow disabling it if necessary and to avoid loading it twice (see [`:help ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin)).

The `let b:did_ftplugin = 1` is omitted from this file because the intent of this file is to increment the default filetype plugin for quickfix, and not override. If this line was added then the settings at `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/qf.vim` would be skipped, as explained at [`:help ftplugin-overrule`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#ftplugin%2doverrule).

Comment: Thanks very much! But What does `b:did_ftplugin` mean? Your script seems to not change it anywhere. I have tried it in my vimrc and It works!

Comment: @tamlok glad I could help. Note that you are not supposed to copy that to your vimrc, but to a file as mentioned in the first phrase. Vim handles that kind of file in a special manner. I updated the question about the `b:did_ftplugin`part.